# Windows Phone Universal - Issue in Navigation and On Loading of page

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I am facing a weird problem in windows phone 8.1 page navigation.

I have got two pages.

1. Login page > Consists of app bar in which one of the button take us to second page.
2. Second page is Cached using MVVM i.e Registered the Second page to IOC on launch of app and binding the instance of it to page 2 XAML.
3. In the Second page View model Constructor I am making Server call to get the data.

Problems facing.

1. On Clicking the app bar button to navigate to second page, the app stays in the first page until the second page make server call and get the response. Then its navigating.

But actual behavior must be it should navigate to second page and wait there to get response showing progress bar.

2. One quick fix is I made the thread to stop for some 50 millisecond in page 2 constructor of view model and then made service call

It navigated to Second page immediately and waited there until response but the previous page App Bar still displays until I get the response.

I even find the quick solution for it by Collapsing the App bar just before Navigating to that page.

I know these quick fixes are not good. So please help me to find out the problem or if you already know please revert back with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use constructor to initiate the web service calls . Use `OnNavigatedTo` or `Page_Loaded` event .

Comment: Null Pointer, Even putting it in On PageLoaded its taking time to render page. the Page background is a local Image but its rendering after I get the response.

Comment: How you are sending web request? Can you include some code ?

Comment: Its just a Http Post request, 
HttpsService httpSrvc = new HttpsService();
            IProgress<HttpProgress> progress = new Progress<HttpProgress>(ProgressHandler);
            string Response = string.Empty;
            Response = await httpSrvc.getHttpResp(RequestUrl, "", isToggleOn, progress);